# Globally replacing a string

Tags: vi

I would like to use the global command 'g' to replace a string, e.g. replace hello with world
I execute the command: s/hello/world/g
I used this command before in nvi (now I only have vi) and it worked.
This time however, the command executes only on the words on one line, not throughout the file.

I am using t shell.

Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

In regular `vi`, you need to prefix the command with `%` to operate on every line:

```
:%s/hello/world/g
```

Note that `%` is equivalent to the explicit range `1,$` in SteveP's answer, in case you wondered what the difference is.

Answer (score 2):

In `vi` you could precede the command with a `%` to make the search and replace take place over the entire file.

`%s/hello/world/g`

Use with caution obviously :)

Answer (score 1):

In vi, will need:

```
1,$s/hello/world/g
```