# Search and Replace in Vi

Tags: unix, vi

I used to use some interactive search and replace in Vi but I totally forgot about it.
Let's explain what I remember because I am currently confused when tried to find out the official ways to replace:

It was close to search by :/pattern but something more like :/pattern/replacement and then I could approve one by one every found string and jump to next occurence by pressing 'n' or selectively replace with the replacement pressing 'r'.

Did I dream that? All I see are regex to do replacements at once and alternatively asking you for a confirmation!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Globally replacing a string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15280576/globally-replacing-a-string)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A solution without regex:

Search the word you want to replace with: 
`/foo` or `?foo` for backward search.

Type `cw` to change the word to a new one.

Press `n` to get to the next occurrence of this word and now either:
 `.` to replace the word or `n` for next occurrence.

Answer (score 2):

Add `c` to the flags.

For example

```
:%s/pattern/replacement/c
```

Searches globally for `pattern` and asks you whether to replace it with `replacement`

See the [vim documentation](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/change.html#:substitute) for more information about these flags.

Comment: Are you sure using c is the only way to replace for each occurrence? That's what I saw in the docs, but I remember another way. PErhaps another vi (vim) or mode or version?

Comment: It is the way I use for this. I do not know whether there are other possibilities to do the same. Maybe someone else will provide a different answer... :)